# Cordova how to get Item details like name, price, image using a barcode?

Tags: api, cordova, hybrid

I'm creating a Cordova application to scan product barcodes. Using the barcode details, how can we get the product's name, price, image? Someone please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: If an answer helped you at all, don't forget to mark it as such! If not, then we'll see if we can help more if you give us some feedback! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Normally the product details themselves are not stored in the barcode itself. Barcodes are just strings of numbers and/or letters which act as a unique lookup for a database. The database would have to be populated with product data.

There are online resources which help with this, but most developers of bespoke barcode reading apps also have their databases populated with bespoke data relevant to the product lines involved.

As a side note, certain products (such as monthly magazines) have bar codes that come in two parts. The first half is unique to that magazine and the second smaller half is the month of issue (i.e. 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You must put on the bar code an ID that identifies your product. Then, once you scanned it, you search on your database this ID and get the information you want.